# label is not working in matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu-14.04

I am facing this Weird behavior of matplotlib scatter plot in which label is not working. Please see the code snippet below-

```
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def get_data():
    n = 10
    theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, n)
    z = np.linspace(-2, 2, n)
    r = z**2 + 1
    x = r * np.sin(theta)
    y = r * np.cos(theta)
    return x, y, z

x, y, z = get_data()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o', label='plot label')
ax.scatter(x, y, z+1, c='b', marker='^', label='scatter label')

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

The above code produces following plot (notice that the label corresponding to scatter plot is missing)-

[image]

Surprisingly, I am getting following error if `ax.plot` is commented-

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py:4747: UserWarning: No labeled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.
  warnings.warn("No labeled objects found. "
```

Below is the information about the system-

- Python 2.7.6
- matplotlib version: 1.3.1
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit

**Any workaround to show the label of scatter plot, please?**

Comment: I guess the obvious solution is to update matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run you code in my environment and it works with both label showing.
Here is my versions

- Python: 2.7.12
- matplotlib: 2.2.2

So you might just need to update the matplotlib.

Comment: Apparently, it seems an isssue with `matplotlib version < 2`. The code works fine on another PC having matplotlib 2. Let me update it please!